# to create graph in asp.net i need data in array inside array format

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays

I have to make a dynamic graph in asp.net. for this i need this type of data structure:- [[0, 0, 8], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 7] array inside array ,

i have used array.push ,but that convert my data set into this format:

```
 'for (var i = 0; i < forth.length; i++)
      {
         result.push([present2[i], present1[i], present3[i]]);
      }
  [0, 0, 8, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 7].'
```

I have 3 set of array: present2,present1,present3
     'present2:-[0,1,2,3,4,5]
      present1:-[0,1,2,0,1,2]
      present3:-[8,2,7,1,4,2]'

now i want to create this type of structure using them 
      '[[0, 0, 8], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 7]]'
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var present2=[0,1,2,3,4,5], present1=[0,1,2,0,1,2] ,present3=[8,2,7,1,4,2];
var result=[];
for (var i = 0; i < present2.length; i++)
{
   result.push([present2[i], present1[i], present3[i]]);
}
console.log(result);

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, more or less. Where is result defined?

This works:

```
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < forth.length; i++)
  {
     result.push([present2[i], present1[i], present3[i]]);
  }
```